# Count occurrences of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm working on something to give users a preview of changes they have made in a form where I compare serialised arrays of objects from the forms fields before and after changes. This all works fine, but I needed to exclude the 'product[territory_ids][]' elements for which there are many as I don't need such a deep level of comparison. The code below works fine.

```
// Get product form values before any changes are made
// and serialise them into an array of objects
$(".product_form_edit").ready(function() {
    form_before = $(".product_form_edit").serializeArray()

    // Using Underscore JS take out all off the product[territory_ids][] elements
    // as they cause comparison to fail. 
    // We'll do a count comparision of the number of territories set separately 
    $.each(form_before, function(i){
        form_before = _.without(form_before, _.findWhere(form_before, {name: 'product[territory_ids][]'}));
    });

    console.log(form_before);

});
```

What I do need to do and am struggling with is detecting a change in the number of 'product[territory_ids][]' elements that are checked.

I thought some kind of variation of:

```
$.each(form_before, function(i){
    form_before = _.without(form_before, _.findWhere(form_before, {name: 'product[territory_ids][]'}));
});
```

Like:

```
$.each(form_before, function(i){
   _.countBy(form_before, _.findWhere(form_before, {name: 'product[territory_ids][]'}));
}).length;
```

Might work, but this and lots of other attempts just return undefined.

Can anyone help? I'm sure it's way simpler than i'm making it.

Comment: Totally conjecture, but why doesn't `form_before.length` work, where you have your `console.log`?

Comment: Also, I'm really confused as to why you've wrapped your `_.without` in a `$.each`

Comment: That does return the total number of form elements, 175 in this case. But what I need is a count of the checked product[territory_ids][] checkboxes, of which there are 256 options. In my test case I have 105 checked so that's the number i'm trying to count.

Comment: The _.without in a $.each is the result of hacking this to death to be honest. But it does work, so reluctant to refactor too much. I probably will once I can nail this checked checkbox count.

Comment: I should probably add that I primary code with Ruby so anything JS based I do is usually a bit of a stab in the dark.

Comment: Any chance we could get a "working" (broken) example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I'll give it a go but this is part of massive app so i'll have to extract these bits.

Comment: I assume your interface is already telling you to do so, but I'm already in the JS Room chat if you want to continue to discuss there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, after a little messing around [with an example I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/bvx6whLv/), I came to the conclusion that you probably want to be using `_.filter` to get your array of checkboxes. `filter` will always return an array, so you should get a count of 0 when there are no checkboxes checked.

```
$('#serialize').click(function() {
    var data = $('#testForm').serializeArray(),
        checkboxes = _.filter(data, function(i) {
            return i.name === 'xyz';
        });

    console.log(data, checkboxes);
    console.log(data.length, checkboxes.length);
});
```

Comment: Ok, that looks promising. I'll see if I can get that working. Thanks for your help.